# Extjs 6.0 - ItemSelector: how to programmatically focus/highlight an element?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, itemselector

I have a ItemSelector component inside a Window. I have implemented a search functionality that dynamically finds the matching entry based on user's keyboard input.

Now I just want to highlight/focus such item inside the ItemSelector.

I'm looking for something like:

```
// when the search returned a result and got the related index in the store
function onSearchPerformed(index) {
    var cmp = this;
    cmp.itemSelector.setSelected(index); // here I'd be highlighting the entry
}
```

**Example**

Imagine a simple ItemSelector like [this one](http://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/rtfd2.2.2/_images/itemselector11.png) taken from the web.

User types 'Delaw' and my search function detects that there is an entry with name Delaware and it's at position 3 in the store.

All I want to do is to programmatically highlight the row/entry 'Delaware' just as if you clicked on it.

Comment: Which component? Is that a grid or combo? A fiddle would be great.
Basically you need to find the cmp and simply use cmp.focus().

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not using a correct terminology. I don't understand how grid/combo fits into here. An element of mine extending Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector is created and given a store. Whenever a user types into the keyboard, a search-function it's triggered, that returns the position of the element in the store. Do you suggest that I just do cmp.itemSelector.getStore()[position].focus() and the row in the ItemSelector will be highlighted? Please tell me if I'm being too ambiguous  or I'm confusing you.

Comment: For example, `cmp.selector.getStore.data.items[5].focus()` does not work.
I can't post a fiddle unfortunately, due to code size and privacy, but I don't believe it's necessary anyway.

Comment: @devbnz forgot to mention you

Comment: Can you share the component / fiddle? Your code actually tries to set focus on a record (from an ext store), this wont work. You need to run focus on a component. you can check that with cmp.isComponent.

Comment: Alright. I took a very simple example from the web which you can find here
[link](https://pastebin.com/yGVBLr7c). Just copy and paste into https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home (I can't save fiddles, sorry). In order to simplify thighs, can you show me how you would highlight item 'Seven' programmatically in the launch function?@devbnz

Comment: I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: The best way to do what you want is to create a chained store that will be filtered by whatever you type in the textfield. As you type you should be able to get all records inside that chained store and then call your `ItemSelector.getSelectionModel().select(records)`.

Comment: Altough I have marked devbnz answer as correct, I ended up using @guilherme-lopes answer. They both work well, but the latter triggers selectionchange events which in my case is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ux component uses a boundList, or better 2 of them. 
A from and a toList.

You need to get a reference to the right boundlist.

More on that you will find here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/src/ItemSelector.js.html

Basically you can do something like this:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24ec

```
afterrender: function(cmp){
                    Ext.defer(function(){
                      var boundlist = cmp.down('boundlist');
                        item = boundlist.all.item(1);
                        boundlist.highlightItem(item);
                    },300);
                }
```

After you have a ref to the correct boundlist, you can simply highlight the item using:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.view.BoundList.html#method-highlightItem

Take care that you may need to call following function before:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.view.BoundList.html#method-clearHighlight

To find the correct item should't be too hard.

Comment: You just need to remember to boundList.clearHighlight(); before highlighting another item @devbnz

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways to solve the issue**

---

One is by following @devbnz answer, marked as correct. This is preferable, if you just want to **graphically** highlight the entry without triggering any event.

However, by hovering on other entries, you will lose the highlight on your current entry.

---

The second one, as suggested by @guilherme-lopes in the comments, may be preferable in cases in which you want the selection to act as if you actually clicked on an entry, which will trigger the `selectionchange` event and similar...

---

Depending on the situation, I ended up using either.